# SSH for running a remote binary stalls

Tags: bash, ssh, raspberry-pi

I am configuring a vs-code extension to send a cross-compiled binary to a raspberry pi.

Every step from compiling to copying the file runs fine.

```
ssh pi@123.123.123.123 "sudo mkdir /home/pi/remotePi/"; 
ssh pi@123.123.123.123 "sudo rm /home/pi/remotePi/blink_example";
ssh pi@123.123.123.123 "sudo chown pi /home/pi/remotePi/"; 
scp -l 8192 build/blink_example pi@123.123.123.123:/home/pi/remotePi/ && 
ssh pi@123.123.123.123 "echo "scp complete"" && 
ssh pi@123.123.123.123 "/home/pi/remotePi/blink_example"
```

Output:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/pi/remotePi/’: File exists
blink_example                                                                                                                     100% 8692   277.3KB/s   00:00    
scp complete
```

But when I try to run the file through an SSH command, the command stalls.

```
ssh pi@123.123.123.123 "home/pi/remotePi/blink_example"
```

It will eventually run, but it can take around 10 minutes. If I ssh into the pi and run the binary through an actual terminal, it runs immediately.

I have noticed that when it finally runs (using my extension), there are a lot of print statements (the test code just prints the read value from a pin). Does that mean it is running, but I'm maybe not getting the prints until there is enough to fill a packet?

So my question is, how can I run a binary on a remote machine and receive the terminal output in a timely manner?

---

**Edit**

I modified my program to not have any delays between print statements (essentially spamming stdout). This resulted in the ssh command `ssh pi@123.123.123.123 "/home/pi/remotePi/blink_example"` to return immediately and with all the prints.

This leads me to believe that there is a buffer that I need to fill (or limit the size of) before any terminal information is returned to the local device from the remote.

Comment: I don't really under the problem, but you might try `mkdir -p /home/pi/remotePi` and you won't get an error if it already exists.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Every ssh command I send executes and returns immediately, but my command to run the binary delays. The binary isn't anything large or complex, so it should return something immediately. And thanks for the tip with ```mkdir -p``` .

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution, but it doesn't answer any of the questions about why spamming stdout will cause ssh to give a terminal output sooner.

In the original blink_example, I was using `printf("pin 17: %d\n", digitalRead(17));` for displaying the value.

I converted the test application to c++ (not a terribly difficult task) and used `std::cout << "pin 17: " << digitalRead(17) << std::endl;`. Using this caused the terminal to give feedback right away.